# callbackDispatcher method not responding while using Workmanager().registerOneOffTask in IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, background, flutter-workmanager

I am trying to run workmanager package on IOS. It works fine on android but doesn't work on IOS. I am using iphone 14 to test. I did setup for ios following [iosSetup](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/blob/master/IOS_SETUP.md).
callbackDispatcher doesn't respond.

This is my key

```
    const simpleTaskKey = "be.tramckrijte.workmanagerExample.simpleTask";
```

This is the function that is not responding at all

```
 void callbackDispatcher() {
      Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
      switch (task) {
        case simpleTaskKey:
          print("$simpleTaskKey was executed. inputData = $inputData");

          final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

          prefs.setBool("test", true);
          print("Bool from prefs: ${prefs.getBool("test")}");
       break;
 
         case Workmanager.iOSBackgroundTask:
         print("The iOS background fetch was triggered");
         Directory? tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
         String? tempPath = tempDir.path;
         print(
           "You can access other plugins in the background, for example 
         Directory.getTemporaryDirectory(): $tempPath");
      break;
     }

    return Future.value(true);
   });
 }
```

code that initializes workmanager

```
  ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("Start the Flutter background service"),
              onPressed: () {
                Workmanager().initialize(
                  callbackDispatcher,
                  isInDebugMode: true,
                );
              },
            ),
```

code to trigger reisterOneOffTask

```
         ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("Register OneOff Task"),
              onPressed: () {
                Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
                  simpleTaskKey,
                  simpleTaskKey,
                  inputData: <String, dynamic>{
                    'int': 1,
                    'bool': true,
                    'double': 1.0,
                    'string': 'string',
                    'array': [1, 2, 3],
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
```

my info.plist

```
<key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>be.tramckrijte.workmanagerExample.simpleTask</string>
</array>
```

my AppDekegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import workmanager

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
override func application(
_ application: UIApplication,
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
) -> Bool {
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
WorkmanagerPlugin.registerTask(withIdentifier: 
"be.tramckrijte.workmanagerExample.simpleTask")

UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(TimeInterval(/* Your Desired 
Interval for Background Tasks */)) 
return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

}